# Trying to use map on a Spark DataFrame

Tags: java, apache-spark, java-8, apache-spark-sql

I recently started experimenting with both Spark and Java. I initially went through the famous `WordCount`example using `RDD` and everything went as expected. Now I am trying to implement my own example but using DataFrames and not RDDs.

So I am reading a dataset from a file with

```
DataFrame df = sqlContext.read()
        .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
        .option("inferSchema", "true")
        .option("delimiter", ";")
        .option("header", "true")
        .load(inputFilePath);
```

and then I try to select a specific column and apply a simple transformation to every row like that

```
df = df.select("start")
        .map(text -> text + "asd");
```

But the compilation finds a problem with the second row which I don't fully understand (The start column is inferred as of type `string`).

> Multiple non-overriding abstract methods found in interface scala.Function1

Why is my lambda function treated as a Scala function and what does the error message actually mean?

Answer (score 21):

If you use the `select`function on a dataframe you get a dataframe back. Then you apply a function on the `Row`datatype not the value of the row. Afterwards you should get the value first so you should do the following:

`df.select("start").map(el->el.getString(0)+"asd")`

But you will get an RDD as return value not a DF

Comment: You also need to have .javaRDD() before map. Also from what I understand there is no clear way to apply a function to the rows of a DataFrame and get back a DataFrame right?

Comment: maybe you can try: ````df.select("start").forEach(el->el.getString(0)+"asd")````

Answer (score 5):

I use concat to achieve this

```
df.withColumn( concat(col('start'), lit('asd'))
```

As you're mapping the same text twice I'm not sure if you're also looking to replace the first part of the string? but if you are, I would do:

```
df.withColumn('start', concat(
                      when(col('start') == 'text', lit('new'))
                      .otherwise(col('start))
                     , lit('asd')
                     )
```

This solution scales up when using big data, as it's concatinating two columns instead of iterating over values.

Comment: could you please let me know how to handle this use-case in java https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63668096/adding-a-new-column-using-withcolumn-from-a-lookup-table-dynamically  ...

Comment: I'm at work atm but can have a look later but check out this answer first https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63537324/can-i-use-regexp-replace-or-some-equivalent-to-replace-multiple-values-in-a-pysp/63538579?noredirect=1#comment112507451_63538579

Comment: thank you so much for your quick reply , sure , please guide me to fix this use-case ....i need to replace the value of one column with value of another if it first one is null ...the link posted here show value replace with another. Can you help me please

Comment: I am not able to perform multiple withColumns in a loop of collection ...which is resulting in two datasets...