# adding a new column using withColumn from a lookup table dynamically

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using spark-sql-2.4.1v with Java 8. I have a scenario where I need to dynamically add a column from a look up table.

I have data frame with columns
A, B, C , ..., X,Y, Z

When few (original) columns ( Ex: A,B,C) values are null , i need to take/substitute column( Ex: X,Y,Z) values else take the original column values.
I will get this mapping information as part of business logic.
If that is the case i will follow something like below hard-coded code

```
 Dataset<Row>  substitutedDs = ds
                  .withColumn("A",
                             when(col("A").isNull() , col("X").cast(DataTypes.StringType))
                             .otherwise(col("A").cast(DataTypes.StringType))
                          )
                  .withColumn("C",
                             when(col("C").isNull() , col("Z").cast(DataTypes.StringType))
                             .otherwise(col("C").cast(DataTypes.StringType))
```

Which is working fine. But I need to do this dynamically/configurable to avoid hard-coding.

I will get look up table with columns "code" and "code_substitutes" information as below

```
-------------------------
| Code | Code_Substitute |
-------------------------
  A         X
  B         Y
  C         Z
-------------------------
```

I need to dynamically construct above "substitutedDs" , how can this be done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Java8, you can use this [Stream.reduce()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-U-java.util.function.BiFunction-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) overload:

```
final Dataset<Row> dataframe = ...;
final Map<String, String> substitutes = ...;

final Dataset<Row> afterSubstitutions = codeSubstitutes.entrySet().stream()
    .reduce(dataframe, (df, entry) ->
            df.withColumn(entry.getKey(), when(/* replace with col(entry.getValue()) when null */)),
            (left, right) -> { throw new IllegalStateException("Can't merge two dataframes. This stream should not be a parallel one!"); }
    );
```

The combiner (last argument) is supposed to merge two dataframes processed in parallel (if the stream was a `parallel()` stream), but we'll simply not allow that, as we're only invoking this logic on a `sequential()` stream.

---

A more readable/maintainable version involves an extra-step for extracting the above logic into dedicated methods, such as:

```
    // ...
    Dataset<Row> nullSafeDf = codeSubstitutes.entrySet().stream()
        .reduce(dataframe, this::replaceIfNull, this::throwingCombiner);
    // ...
}


private Dataset<Row> replaceIfNull(Dataset<Row> df, Map.Entry<String, String> substitution) {
    final String original = substitution.getKey();
    final String replacement = substitution.getValue();
    return df.withColumn(original, when(col(original).isNull(), col(replacement))
            .otherwise(col(original)));
}

private <X> X throwingCombiner(X left, X right) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Combining not allowed");
}
```

Comment: As a side note, you can also use some dummy/random combiner like `(left, right) -> left` and just assume the combiner will never be invoked. However, I'd say you want this to fail (ideally, in tests) if anyone changes `.stream()` to `.parallelStream()`.

Comment: If you're using this approach more than once, you may want to extract that `throw` into some `throwingCombiner()` utility method...

Comment: thank you , but in this reduce(dataframe, (df, entry) ....what is this df ? where do we get it here ?

Comment: Have a look at the Javadoc for that `reduce` method: the second parameter is a BiFunction that you control taking whatever Dataframe was accumulated so far (starting with the original one, passed in as the `identity` param) and the new element to "append" to it (a map entry, in this case) and returning the new Dataframe that "incorporates" that element...
So it's the reduce method itself that will provide that `df` for every invocation, starting with `dataframe` and then taking the result of applying `replaceIfNull` with each entry.
makes sense?

Comment: .reduce function using javaapi is not working ...instead of codeSubstitutes , I am trying to use List<Tuple2<String,String>> ...this reduce throwing compilation error ... The method reduce(Tuple2<String,String>, BinaryOperator<Tuple2<String,String>>) in the type Stream<Tuple2<String,String>> is not applicable for the arguments (Tuple2<String,String>, (<no type> df, <no type> entry) -> {})

Comment: Have one doubt , why should we use here reduce() with throwingCombiner ? we can use second version of reduce() which takes "identity and accumulator" ?

Comment: how to pass other parameters which are useful inside the "accumilator" method here ? I need to pass ListOfDates inside it.

Comment: in this case , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63826707/converting-sql-query-to-equivalent-spark-query    how can I collect resultDs datasets using reduce/map function ?

Comment: could you please advice what is wrong here in reduce function https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63843599/reduce-result-datasets-into-single-dataset

Comment: To pass other parameters to a method, you can't use a method reference (`this::method`), but a lambda (`arg -> method(arg, something_else, yet_another_one)`). If this functional approach doesn't come naturally to you, you can achieve the same with the classic imperative approach: mutable variables and for loops.

Answer (score 1):

In Scala, I would do like this

```scala
val substitueMapping: Map[String, String] = ??? //this is your substitute map, this is small as it contains columns and their null substitutes

val df = ??? //this is your main dataframe 

val substitutedDf = substituteMapping.keys().foldLeft(df)((df, k) => {
    df.withColumn(k, when(col(k).isNull, col(substituteMapping(k))).otherwise(col(k)))
    //do approproate casting in above which you have done in post
})
```

I think `foldLeft` is not there in Java 8, you can emulate the same by modifying a variable repeatedly and doing iteration on `substituteMapping`.

Comment: unfortunately fold function not available in Java..and its not working when i tried with stream()

Comment: @Dee thanks Dee but i need to replace the value of one column with value of another if it first one is null ...

Comment: "modifying a variable repeatedly" anything modified inside the lambda is not accessible outside for lambda function.

Comment: @BdEngineer you are supposed to modify `var df`, you can access it from lambda